# google maps loading map on button click - loading markers with another button

Tags: google-maps-api-3, onclick, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to load markers on the click of a button, but somewhere i'm missing something.  1.  map pulls out and loads with one button click.  2.  markers load with the click of a different button.  here's what i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="
    <?php  
        $stylesarray = array("field");  
        echo $stylesarray[mt_rand(0,count($stylesarray)-1)];  
    ?>.css">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var map = null;

$(document).ready(function(){   

    var lat=document.getElementById("latitude");
    var long=document.getElementById("longitude");       
    if (navigator.geolocation){
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); 
    } 
     function showPosition(position) {
         lat.value=+position.coords.latitude;
         long.value=+position.coords.longitude;
     }   
    });

function load() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(20,0),
    zoom: 3,
    styles: mapstyle,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    maxZoom: 8,
    minZoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
}

function getmarkers(){
  downloadUrl("markers.php", function(data) {
    //alert ("it works");
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
      var info = markers[i].getAttribute("info");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
      var date = markers[i].getAttribute("date");
      var html =  "<div id='tooltip'><div id='tiptext'>" + info
                  + "<div id='number'>" + id + "</div>"
                  + "<div id='date'>" + date + "</div>" 
                  +  "</div></div>";
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: 'images/mapicon.png'

      });         
      createTooltip(marker, html);
    }
  });

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="mapcontainer">
<form>
    <input type="button" id="map" onClick="load()"></input>  
</form>
<form> 
    <input type="button" onClick="getmarkers()"></input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

xml sample:

```
<markers>
<marker id="330" info="blahblah" date="2012-10-03" latitude="20.00" longitude="-81.00"/>
</markers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map variable is local to your initialize function.  It won't be accessible to the code that loads the markers.

Try defining it globally (outside of any functions):

```
var map = null;
```

Then initialize it in your load function

```
function load() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), {
```

The problem (after syntax errors) with your posted code is that the getmarkers function is local to the load function. It needs to be global to be called by an HTML element click function.

[Live working version based off your example code](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_xml_onclick.html)

Comment: added var map = null; still nothing working correctly.  do i need to pass anything to downloadUrl?  the map loads correctly.  it's the markers where i'm having trouble.

Comment: Can you provide a link or your complete code (or a jsfiddle, probably can't make that work without your xml though...)?

Comment: How about a sample of the xml?

Comment: And the css?  And fixing the syntax errors, there is a missing "}", mapstyle is not defined.

Comment: sample xml included above.  forgot to include the "}" when pasting.  everything's fine except for the markers.  the map loads correctly and the buttons as well.  also, something useful.  the "icon" is not showing under google console > resources > images.  however, the path is correct.  Therefore, I'm guessing there's something within the marker placement code that isn't correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17573/discussion-between-stokexx-and-geocodezip)

Comment: Your map variable is still local to your load function.  Missed the change to remove the "var" from in front of it in your load function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you do not declare the map variable in the global scope. Only in the load function scope, declare it as a global variable and it should work.

```
var map = null; // Declaring map in the global scope

function load() {
    // map references to global scope
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), {
    ...
}

downloadUrl("markerinfo.php", function(data) {
      ...
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, // map references to global scope
        position: point,
        icon: 'images/mapicon.png'

      });         
      createTooltip(marker, html);
    }
});
```

Try wrapping the DownloadUrl function call in another function and call that instead.

```
<input type="button" id="markerload" onClick="getMarkers()"></input>

function getMarkers() {
    downloadUrl("markerinfo.php", function(data) {
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: geocodezip suggested this above, and i'm still having difficulty.

Comment: My bad, I noticed that he answered right after I submitted my answer. Are you getting any javascript console errors?

Comment: to be honest, i'm not sure.  i'm taking on this project as a learning experience.  i placed an alert within downloadUrl and it alerts, so i know it's calling the function properly

Comment: still same issues with wrapping downloadUrl.  it has to be something quite simple.  original code edited above.

Comment: Try opening the javascript console and see if you get any errors, you might get an error that prevents you from executing the rest of the code (from the click and beyond). You open the developer tools by pressing F12 in Chrome, Firefox and IE (7-8+ i think).

Comment: checked in the console.  no errors, all the data comes through from the xml file, the marker icon path is correct.  can't seem to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

function getmarkers() is designed to retrieve all markers with a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
```

To load one marker at a time you will need to increment it for each button click

Ie `Var i =0` globally
Increment i at end of getmarkers() `i++`

You should stop the increments after the last member of array when it gets to `markers.length`

Comment: that's true, david.  i will handle one marker at a time, once i figure out how to load all the markers on the click of a button.  for some reason, the markers are not loading at all when i onClick="getmarkers()"

Comment: Code will not run on my localhost as i don't have the css php file or return from markers.php. But I see that getmarkers() doesn't have closing }